# C#: Detect which side picturebox collides

Tags: c#, collision

I am building a simple BreakOut game using Pictureboxes for the ball, bat and blocks.

```
if( block.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ball.Bounds)){
    // Switch the x OR y direction
    x *= -1;
    // or
    y *= -1;
}
```

The ball moves like:

```
speed = 2;
x = -1; // or 1
y = -1; // or 1
ball.Location.X += speed * x;
ball.Location.Y += speed * y;
```

I need to switch the x direction of the ball when it hits the block on the side
but it needs to switch the y direction when the ball hits the block on the up or down side.

Is there a way to know where it hit the block?

Comment: You know the position you're drawing them both.. isn't this just a bit of relatively simple maths?

Comment: Is the ball only moving in up/down/left/right directions? Will it ever be possible for the objects to collide diagonally?

Comment: The ball is moving vertical only, yes it hits the block, the code so far works, except it doesnt see wich side it hits

Comment: The position might overlap the block so the y coordinate will be in the block and so will the x, it might be simple maths but im really not getting any further :(

Comment: @Robin It all depends on how simple your collision is, but in any case the easiest way to tell which side the ball collided with the block is by comparing their positions (which also depends on the coordinate system that you are using).